# javascript/php div dropdown search results

Tags: javascript, search, dropdownbox

I have a searchbox at the top of a page.  Using ajax I want a div to drop down over the page to display search results.  The key thing is I want the search results to overlay the page underneath rather than push it down.  For this reason, I cannot just have a div underneath the searchbox.  I need to do something a bit more complicated--but I am not sure what.

Following code populates a div under the searchbox.  Can anyone suggest an economical way to get div to go over the page rather than push everything down.  Thanks for any suggestions!

javascript

```
function showResults(str) {

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("results").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";

//some ajax

xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?str="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
<table><tr><td><img src="logo.gif"></td><td>
<input type="text" id="string" onkeyup="showResults(this.value)">
<div id="results"></div><td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2
Main body of page.  All sorts of text and html go here that I do not want pushed down.
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: position the div absolutely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<table><tr><td><img src="logo.gif"></td><td style="position:relative">
<input type="text" id="string" onkeyup="showResults(this.value)">
<div id="results" style="position:absolute"></div><td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2
Main body of page.  All sorts of text and html go here that I do not want pushed down.
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Position relative and absolute will help you to find the solution, and the same time, onload, you need to hide the div, once search result in, you have to show it again.

Comment: This helped.  The results are overlaying the page.  However, they are transparent so the page shows through.  Also, they are not staying in the table but going all the way over to the right of the screen.  Do I need to format the div somehow?

Comment: As position given absolute, you can postion relative to its TD, why do you get transparent, that means you have given some where to transparent. Can you share the code?

Comment: I have not made transparent as far as I know.  Just added in style <div id="results" style="position:absolute"></div>. Can I use css as in a class to to style the div?  Also, when you click outside the box, need a way to make dropdown disappear which it won't do currently.

Comment: And you have to add postion:relative to the hoding TD also

Comment: I styled it with a css tag and it is looking better.  Still some issues but am marking answer right.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks, I did my best, if code was given, i cud help much, Thanks

Comment: By setting background-color:white; it now covers most underlying text.  But one bit of text shows through.  It is styled .username {
whitespace:true;
color:blue;
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
            }
Any idea how to keep this from showing through

Answer (score 1):

You have to position your result div absolutely.

Like :

```
<div id="results" style="position:absolute">
```